# How to check what is wrong with my mobile connection?

Tags: mobile-network

I have a Samsung J3 and recently I notice some irregular 'blackouts' in the mobile connection. Suddenly, the connection is completely interrupted, then the connection is really slow (like 1.9 Mbps in the center of Geneva!), and then it works just fine (with download speeds  well above 10 Mbps).

I restarted the phone, select 'Select automatically' in the available network settings, and talked to the provider. They admitted there was a network problem, but I am using it at two very different places.

So how to find out if it is my phone or the network?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have that model device accessible to verify the accuracy/currency, but here is a site that specifies test codes for [Samsung J3](https://www.hardreset.info/devices/samsung/samsung-j330-galaxy-j3-2017/codes/).  In particular, I believe #5 & #6 would offer diagnostic data in regards to cellular network (YMMV based on carrier / geography).

That said, what you are able to interpret from said data would be another story all together.  As @Robert suggests, it may be simpler to first eliminate possible scenarios using other devices you may have available.  There may also be applications that can give more verbose information than the test menu cited.

Here's another resource for you to review in regards to your network settings configuration as specific to your mobile [carrier](https://www.imei.info/carriers/).

I hope that helps, and good luck!

Answer (score 2):

Tracing networking problems in mobile networks is pretty complicated.

Therefore from your perspective there is only one way to find out if it is your phone or not: Use a different phone (different model preferred) using your SIM card at the same places.

If you encounter the same performance drops you know that it is not your phone. If not it may be your phone but that is not for sure.